# Deixar checkbox obrigatório

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Preciso de uma função onde selecionar um checkbox é obrigatorio.
Tenho 6 checkboxes e usuário deve selecionar somente um.

Ex:

```
<input type ="checkbox" name="xx"...>
<label for="xx".......>
<input type ="checkbox" name="xx"...>
<label for="xx".......>
```

Valeu

Comment: Nesse caso deves usar `type="radio"` e não `type="checkbox"`, e tens de dar o mesmo `name` a todos os 6

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146567/129